# Semaphores in C Linux Programming

Tags: c, linux, centos

I'm taking over some C code running in Linux (Centos) with extensive use of semaphores. 
The way the code is written :

./Program1

This program launches a bunch of processes which makes use of mutexes and semaphores.

./Program2

This program also launches a bunch of processes which makes use of mutexes and semaphores.

I've realised that Program1 and Program2, they make use of semaphores with the same names. 
In Linux C programming, can different programs use the same semaphores? 
My guess is no, but the same naming is confusing the hell out of me. They are using the same source code to launch and handle the semaphores.

The semaphores are invoked using the following commands:

**semget
semctl
semop**
I've read that these are called processes semaphores.. if Program1 creates SEMAPHORE1, can Program2 access SEMAPHORE1?

Appreciate any help here, thanks!

Comment: To get a better answer, it might be helpful to share some relevant segments of the code you're maintaining.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you mean named semaphores (or even unnamed semaphores stored in shared memory, both which can be created with `sem_open`), they generally *are* shared amongst processes.

Semaphores using `semget` and related calls use an ID key rather than a name but their usage patterns are similar.

Semaphores are one of the IPC (inter-process communication) methods.

You *can* create a one-process-only semaphore by using an unnamed variant in non-shared memory and this will only be accessible to threads of the given process but, in my experience, that's not a common use case. The `semget` family of calls can also give you process-private semaphores.

Mutexes, on the other hand, tend to be more used within a single process for inter-thread communication but there is even a variant of them that can work inter-process.

You create a `pthread_mutexattr` (attribute) which allows sharing of mutexes and then use that attribute when initialising the mutex you want to share. Obviously, the mutex needs to be in shared memory so that multiple processes can get at it.

Comment: The semaphores are created using semget, semctl, are these the POSIX semaphores you are talking about?

Comment: @lppier, that's another way of creating them, just using a semaphore-set ID rather than a name in the `/dev/shm` namespace. Those ones can also be private or shared, depending on the arguments given to `semget`.